# VBA: Stop Word from adding new line to selected text

Tags: vba, ms-word

Whenever I select a section of text in MS Word using this code:

```
Dim aRange As Range
Set aRange = ActiveDocument.Range( _
 Start:=ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.Start, _
 End:=ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(3).Range.End)
  aRange.Select
```

everything is fine except that Word automatically alters the selection to add a new line character at the end of the selection. How to avoid it? Perhaps it is possible to change the selection so that it will not include a new line character.

My question is similar to another [one already asked](https://superuser.com/q/962710/388634), but I would like it to do it using VBA.

Comment: Just do as stated in the [answer](http://superuser.com/questions/962710/how-to-make-microsoft-word-selection-behave-like-it-would-in-a-plain-text-editor) while recording the macro and you will get the desired code auto-generated plain and simple

Answer (score 0):

When you work with selections on the keyboard you use Shift + Left/Right Arrow keys to change the extent of the selection. In the Word object model there's an equivalent you can use with the Range object; actually, there's a set of methods: MoveStart, MoveEnd, MoveWhile, MoveUntil

In this case, you need the MoveEnd method. You can move the end point by a specific set of units, such as characters, words, paragraphs - you want to move by one character, going "backwards", so:

```
aRange.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
aRange.Select
```

Comment: Does this solution work on your system? On my Word 2016 it doesn't seem to work, even if I change Word settings according to [this post](http://superuser.com/a/962714/388634). Your solution itself should do what is is supposed to do; for example, if I change -1 to -2, the last character is unchecked but the new line character is still present when I copy the selection to, say, a  plain text editor.

Comment: It works fine for me, on both Word 2010 and Word 2016. At least as far as selecting properly. Copying to anywhere else is not part of your question or problem description - you really need to include EVERYTHING when you ask a question!

Comment: FWIW this appears to also be the case when you select and copy manually. My best guess would be that this is inherent in how Word MUST put the informaton on the Clipboard for use in other applications. In the underlying, native Word Open XML Word MUST close the w:p (paragraph) tag, it can't just leave it hanging. If this is a problem for you, you need to work paragraph by paragraph. Then Word can pass just the w:r (text run), no Paragraph information needs to be attached as is the case when additional paragraphs are included.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
doc.Paragraphs(1).Range.Select
Selection.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
Selection.Copy
```