# Extra character when copying text from Word table cell to spreadsheet cell

Tags: ms-word, copy

I am copying text from table cells in a Word document to cells in an Excel spreadsheet.

I have a VBA macro in Word that mostly works using the following statement to copy the cell text

```
nWorksheet.Cells(nRow, nCol).Text = oDocument.Range(Start:=oCell.Range.Start, End:=oCell.Range.End - 1)
```

Unfortunately, what ends up in the spreadsheet cell seems to have an extra invisible character that acts like a newline or carriage return.

Does anyone know what this extra character is or how to avoid it?

Thanks!

Comment: It very well may be a newline character at the end of each row in the word table. Have you tried the MoveEnd command like in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35183908/14077491)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using this small function to return the text from a cell, as I always forget the logic, but calling `getCellText` is easy to remember.

```vb
Public Function getCellText(c As Word.cell) As String
    'returns text without cell-end
    getCellText = Replace(c.Range.Text, Chr(13) & Chr(7), vbNullString)
    'alternative:
    'getCellText = Left(c.Range.text, Len(c.Range.text) - 2)
End Function
```

`Chr(13) & Chr(7)` represents the cell end that you need to remove.
Therefore yo need either to move the end by two characters or replace it.

You can use it like this:

`nWorksheet.Cells(nRow, nCol).Text = getCellText(oCell)`

Comment: Thanks Ike. getCellText(oCell) returns the right string, but I get "unable to set the Text property of the Range class when I execute  `nWorksheet.Cells(nRow, nCol).Text = getCellText(oCell)`

Comment: A quick search on stackoverflow told me I had to use the .Value property as in  `nWorksheet.Cells(nRow, nCol).Value = getCellText(oCell)` All good! Thanks!

Comment: Very good. As you're new on SO: Please don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you to solve your problem. See also [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)